# I want to get current page URL in React JSX

Tags: reactjs

I am in the `xyz.jsx` file, and I want to get the current page URL and match the value.

For example:

```
  getCurrentURL = www.testreact.reactadmin.com/abc/23

  value = admin

  if(valuematch)
     { return true }
  else 
     { return false }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current page URL, you can use:

```
window.location.href
```

To match the value you can use:

```
const url = window.location.href

const value = 'admin'

if(url.includes(value)) {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer, i was using the same but window.location.href through exception. it shows Exception in rendering!

Message: window is not defined

Comment: The `window is not defined` error occurs for multiple reasons, so it would be easier to understand if you could share your `xyz.jsx` code.

Comment: can't share complete file.. so giving u over view
import React from 'react';
import Snippet from 'shared_components/snippet';

class CardGroupContainer extends React.PureComponent {
  renderCard =({)}=>{
   // here define the above shared code
}